# Flutter how to show data from class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a class like this

```
class Collection with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Items> _items = [];

  void addData(Items day) {
    print(day.name);
    print(day.id);
    _items.add(day);
    print(_items);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Items { 
  String name;
  String comments;
  int id;
  Items({required this.name, required this.comments, required this.id});
}
```

I am inserting data in _items like this

```
 Collection().addData(Items(name: "a", comments: "sda", id: 12));
```

I can see on addData function its printing values correctly

but when i am showing this in my widget its not showing

```
   ListView.builder(
                itemCount: Collection()._items.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  print(Collection()._items.length);
                  return Text('name ${Collection()._items[index].name} id ${Collection()._items[index].id}');
                })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call the `Collection()` constructor, you're making a different instance of the `Collection` class. You need to create an instance using

```dart
final collection = Collection();
```

And then use that object in your builder.

It is better to use `final` than `var`, because that ensures that the `collection` object won't get reassigned to a new instance.

Comment: Thanks but its not saving data inside _items mean when i add data its showing in ListView but when i comeback on page its showing empty _items and if i add again then its showing fine. I am doing something wrong my data isnt saving in _items

Comment: You're probably looking at a different runtime instance. When you navigate away from the page, you'll lose the `collection` instance if that is a member of your widget. One way to address this is using the BLoC pattern. If you keep the `collection` instance in a bloc, you won't lose it when you navigate away.

Comment: A way to visualise this is to create an explicit constructor in the `Collection` class, and put a breakpoint into the constructor.